# How to filter an array of arrays by every nth child in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to filter out every 5th date from my data and running into trouble. My data is organized as

```
> data_2 (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]  
   0: {id: 'Team1', values: Array(30)}
    id: 'Team1'  
    values: Array(30)
      0: {date: Thu Nov 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), measurement: 554}
      1: {date: Fri Nov 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), measurement: 584}
      ...
```

I've tried

```
data_2.filter(function(d,i) { return i%4 == 3 && i > 0 })
```

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202322/add-a-circle-for-every-nth-data-element-d3-js) but end up with an empty array. I'm basically trying to retrieve the data for every 4th date. Any suggestions?

EDIT: fixed the modulo operation above

Comment: When dividing a number by four, the remainder will never be four: Otherwise you divided wrong. This is why your returned array is empty. You likely want to use i%5 == 4

Comment: @AndrewReid Every 4th element is `i%4 === 3`

Comment: Thanks Andrew - so if I'm trying to do every 3rd as in your previous post's example: 

data_2.filter(function(d,i) { return i%3 == 3 && i > 0 })

It's still coming up as empty - what am I thinking about incorrectly?

Comment: `i%3 == 3` and `i%4 == 4` are always false. It's mathematically impossible. You want `i%3 == 2` resp. `i%4 == 3`

Comment: Apologies - so when I try data_2.filter(function(d,i) { return i%3 == 2 && i > 0 }) it's only returning the 2nd team's information, where I'm trying to get at all teams information but every 3rd date

Comment: `i` starts with `0` and `i%3 == 2` is true for `2`, `5`, `8`, .... That's the third, sixth, ninth, ...  element.

Comment: @tnerbusas, you have copied my typo from the other post, my apologies. (glad that you helped me spot it)

Comment: @tnerbusas, you have an array of objects representing teams, each team having a child array of dates and you wish to return every nth date for a single team or all teams? Or is neither a correct interpretation?

Comment: Hi @AndrewReid The latter. I want to get every nth date for all teams.

data_2.filter(function(d,i) { return i%3 == 2 && i > 2 }) is filtering on the teams element, however I'm trying to filter on the values element - should I be adding in data_2.filter(function(d,i,j) { return j%3 == 2 && j > 2 }) ?

Comment: You should read [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The third argument is the whole array.

Comment: @jabaa Right - so that won't work. I'm guessing I'd need to nest another filter function to get to the values?

Comment: Do you want to keep this structure (array of objects with containing an array of dates) or do you want an array of dates? For the first case I recommend to use a loop instead of array methods. For the second case I recommend `flatMap`

Comment: @ThomasSablik I need the former, an array of objects containing all data from every 3rd (or 4th) date. I'll try out a loop and see where I get. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can filter it like this:

`data_2.filter((d, i) => { return (i + 1) % 5 })`